# What would be a good SE to ask Cadence question?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I have currently registered for a course on VLSI and learning Cadence Virtuoso for simulation of digital circuits is one of the course objectives. I had questions regarding its use but I am not sure which stack exchange website would be useful. Can anyone suggest?

Comment: [Electronics SE](http://electronics.stackexchange.com) might be what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In electronics.stackexchange.com are already many questions about cadence. 
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/search?q=cadence

I would try it there.